# Book reference about abacuses (abaci)

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, math-history

I'm searching one or more books about abaci. On one side I'm interested in the history of the abacus while on the other side I'm searching for books explaining algorithms used to perform the four basic operations but also square and cubic root which these devices. I'm focusing on Chinese and Japanese abacus but also some reference about Russian abacus will be useful.

As pointed out in the comment below, Wikipedia gives some references but I'm searching for something more specific. To make an example consider the russian abacus where some rods have four beads. I have read these rods are used for counting quarters of kopeks (1/400 of a ruble) but these coins are not in use by about a century so why some abaci being not more than 70 years old still have them? So far the only references I was able to find was in Cyrillic and I'm not able to read Russian.

Any suggestion will be very appreciated.

Comment: there are several references in the wikipedia, were they not sufficient?

Comment: @user619894 I have edit my question to make it more clear. I'm searching for something more specific.